# Retry policy in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to implement retry policy in a project I am working on which uses Entity Framework connecting to MSSQL 2012. I can do the following:

```
using (var model = new MyModel())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            model.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Index < 1000);
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

but it is quite cumbersome to do this everywhere I want to make a query using the model. Is there anyway to implement this in the model itself so that I don't have to worry about it?

One way I thought of is to use inherit the `DbCommand` and override `ExecuteScalar()`, `ExecuteNonQuery()`, etc., so that they repeat the call to the methods of the base class for a certain number of times, but wondering whether there is an easier way to do that?

Comment: Your sample code tries three times, regardless of the result of any previous tries. What is your architecture set up that makes a retry policy necessary?

Comment: Sorry @DaveK, I forgot to add the break statement to break the loop if the fetch is successful. Please see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to do "using the model". You have to implement it manually. Either in i.e. repository or in some "data access adapter" if you're using something like that. Or if you want to go hard core :), you can, of course, create your own IDbConnection, IDbCommand etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure I understood what you mean by in "repository", do you mean like implement the retry policy on the SQL Server side in my case?

Comment: I mean repository pattern: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx .